# Eigenvalues of the fractional power of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Let $A$ be a compact self-adjoint linear operator on a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$ and $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R$ denote an enumeration of the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ with$^1$ $$|\lambda_n|\ge|\lambda_{n+1}|\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.$$

> Let $p>0$. Considering the spectral decomposition of $A$, it is easy to see that $\lambda^p_n$ is an eigenvalue$^2$ of $A^p$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. How can we show that $(\lambda_n^p)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is in fact an enumeration, nonincreasing in absolute value, of $\sigma(A^p)$, i.e. there are no other eigenvalues of $A^p$?

If $A$ has finite rank, the claim is easy to prove by a dimension argument, since eigenspaces with respect to different eigenvalues are known to be orthogonal. But I'm unsure what to do in the infinite-dimensional case.

---

$^1$ If $N:=|\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}|\in\mathbb N$, then $\lambda_n=0$ for all $n>N$.

$^2$ $0$ is terminologically treated as an eigenvalue here.

Comment: How are you defining $A^p$ for noninteger $p$? (One definition of $A^p$ makes this question trivial.)

Comment: The spectral theorem for a compact self-adjoint $A$ is essentially the same as for the finite-dimensional case. $A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n E_n$, where $E_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto the eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda_n$, which must be finite-dimensional (and the eigenvalues have $0$ as the only possible point of accumulation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do specifically with compact, nor with selfadjoint. If $A^p$ makes sense (say via Holomorphic, Continuous, or Borel Functional Calculus), the Spectral Mapping Theorem gives you that 
$$
\sigma(A^p)=\{\lambda^p:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A)\}. 
$$

Comment: Simply my the identity $A=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda_ne_n\otimes e_n$, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean that, by the spectral theorem (for compact operators here), $A$ has the expansion above for some ONB $(e_n)$ of $H$.

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Thanks. If $\mu_1,\ldots,$ are the distinct eigenvalues (this sequence may be end and filled with $0$'s) and $\pi_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto $E_i:=\mathcal N(\mu_i-A)$, can we infer that $A^p=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu_n^p\pi_n$? I'm not sure. I mean $\pi_n$ is an orthogonal projection, but is $\pi_n^p=\pi_n$ for a fractional $p$?

Comment: Yes, $p(\pi_n)=\pi_n\,p(1)$ for any polynomial with $p(0)=0$. Then take limits.

Comment: Okay, last question: Can we also conclude that $\sigma(|A|)=\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in\sigma(A)\}$? If so, is there a relation between the eigenspaces, i.e. if $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$, are $\mathcal N(\lambda-A)$ and $\mathcal N(|\lambda|-|A|)$ related? I've asked for that here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3659689/47771.